# Reference request for probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

What are some good textbooks to learn probability theory at a graduate level (measure theory and all that)? I have read most of Durrett and it's a pretty good book, but I was hoping for another approach to the subject. If possible, it would be great if the reference focused on random walks and markov chains.

Comment: Handbook of Stochastic Methods, Probability with Martingales, and possibly Random perturbations of dynamical systems. Those come to mind.

Comment: My favorite for measure theoretic probability is K L Chung's book. Breiman is a good book too.

Comment: *Adventures in Stochastic Processes* by Sidney Resnick has a chapter on Markov chains and one on random walks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my personal experience, the following texts proved very useful from a graduate standpoint

- *Foundations of Modern Probability*, by O. Kallenberg;
- *Probability Theory I (Graduate Texts in Mathematics)*, by M. Loeve;
- *Probability Theory*, by A. Klenke;
- *A Probability Path*, by S. Resnick.

These are my top four, but there are naturally other options, depending on your taste and what area of probability theory you're more interested in.

Interesting real-life examples can be found in

- *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory*, by Jeffrey Rosenthal.

Hope this helps!